# Populate a Java Spring form with an object transfered from an external application via a web Service in a new tab

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, web-services

Say I have a `spring:form` binded with `MyObject` class and on submit I hit this Controller method:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/saveObject")
    public String saveInterest(@ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject, BindingResult result,
            ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session) throws Exception {

        try {
            // MY NEED IS HERE
            myService.saveMyObject(myObject);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("error when trying to save my object");
        }
        
        return "redirect:/dasboard";
    }
```

What I want to achieve is passing `myObject` to an external application too on submit, by that I mean opening this external application in a new tab with `myObject` filling a similar `spring:form`.

Here is what I did so far :

- Created a Restful Web Service client that hits an external application controller in which I receive `myObject` and fill a `spring:form` with it before returning a `ModelAndView`.

My question is how can I implement this new tab behavior, am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: you `/saveObject` endpoint is called from an UI web application I assume. If I understood correctly you want to open another tab as a "response" to this call of of `/saveObject`? If so this is, purely an UI issue to solve. On the UI where you call the `/saveObject` of your service, you can as well make a request to the external service and opening it on new tab. You already have the myObject on the UI so calling the `/saveObject` plays no role in this scenario.

Comment: Basically to achieve this, you must have an abstract layer like facade layer/api gateway which would broadcast form data to multiple services. 
Along with this, you can use a http rest call to another service with model and view and aggregate the data.
Sending consume only requests are fine but if both the services returns response there are 2 ways ```1st is to use Ajax in UI``` and ```2nd is to use in controller calls to aggregate the responses and then return```

Comment: @Raipe Your first assumption is correct, the endpoint is called from a UI web app. Opening a new tab via javascript is not the trciky part, I do not plan to pass myObject attributes as request parameters, I need to pass myObject as an object in the body of the WS call that is why I used '/saveObject' because it already transfers myObject to the back-end where I will pass it to the WS client as a parameter before saving it in the database so no need to re-invent the wheel. I hope you got it

Comment: @AmmarAkouri I do not quite understand what are you trying to achieve. Maybe you can add some more details on the question? Maybe to add the steps you try to achieve listing what does each of the component (UI, your web app, external app) do at each step.